# Dynamically choose the class the method belongs

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

I have a base class which has  common attributes and functions of  2 classes reader_a and writer_a.  I have another set of 2 classes reader_b and writer_b which are meant for same functionality. the base class is inherited by all the classes.

```
file -A 
class base class (abc.metadata)  
  #all common attributes
class reader(base class)
  def read_image():
    pass
class writer(base class)
  def write_image()
     pass

File B
class reader(base class)
  def read_image():
    pass
class writer  (base class)
  def write_image()
     pass
```

What is the best way to abstract  methods  in reader and writer classes in both files so that I can switch between them dynamically based on a global variable? Global variable is being set based on the file type the user inputs.
At the moment i am calling the  functions separately like to read a image(using file A) I use  fileA.read_image(filepath).
How should I interface my methods to   call read_image if the file type is of file b it should call fileb.read_image()? I am asking how  to define a  api call like read_image() and it should   automatically choose  the function between the 2 files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have multiple implementations of `base` and you want do decide which one to use (in run time) - you need to have something like this:

```
image_handler_type = os.getenv('image_handler','A')
if image_handler_type == 'A':
  image_handler = AReader()
elif mage_handler_type == 'B':
  image_handler = BReader()
...

# the main code uses image_handler without knowing the exact implementation
image_handler.read(...)
```